# best way to store data in session

Tags: php, session

I'm thinking about two ways of storing data in session:

```
$_SESSION['data'] = array(
    'a'=>'a',
    'b'=>'b',
    'c'=>'c'
);
```

or

```
$_SESSION['a'] = 'a';
$_SESSION['b'] = 'b';
$_SESSION['c'] = 'c';
```

Which one is better, especially when the number of SESSION data items is large?

Comment: there is no better in this case. Or define **better**

Comment: `['a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b', 'c' => 'c']`

Comment: I like the array method more. Probably no difference in performance but more organized especially if you have a large number of items

Comment: There is no general "better" answer to the question *How to structure my array*. Yes, that's your question. Sessions are pretty irrelevant here.

Comment: As far as I know, each $_SESSION item is stored in a file. I think that it might be better if I store the whole data in a single array.

Comment: No, the whole `$_SESSION` is stored in one file, not each separate item within `$_SESSION` in a separate file.

Comment: @deceze I got it now. Thank you.

Comment: @Orion: don't think too much about how it is stored. Think about what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It depends on your design and requirements**

**Option 1: array inside session**

If variables `a`, `b` and `c` share some common meaning besides "variables in session", I would use `$_SESSION['data']` to capture them under a common array. In this way you can pass this `data` array and use common operators for it. And still, if you need something else like `data2` you could use session for that. For example if the items refer to items in a shopping cart then I'd put them all inside a common array.

Example:

```
$_SESSION['cart_items'] = array(
  'a' => 1,
  'b' => 2,
  'c' => 5
);
```

**Option 2: using session array directly**

If variables `a`, `b` and `c` refer to generally anything you store in the session and do not share any other semantics, then just put them straight inside `$_SESSION`. Examples of these kind of one time items include: username of currently logged in user, last time the active user loaded the page, etc. In these kind of cases adding the extra `data` array probably would be just useless overhead.

Example:

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = 123;
$_SESSION['last_updated'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of `$_SESSION['data']`?